# try to discover the pattern

Tags: pattern

**Can you find the following circle in this image ?**

> Discribe the angles at which a line intersects the circle.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A child circle is the result of XORing the two parent circles, so the final circle in this case is (N, NE, S, SW).